# Is it possible to access members of one class with pointers of another class if they inherit a common base in C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I haven't been able to figure out a way to do this. Suppose I have two classes A and B, both inherit a class Base. Now in a class say Alpha,I want to create a member function that uses pointers to navigates from one instance of class A to a instance of class B based on some conditions.Can anyone give me an idea how I can do this in C++. Think of the problem like a binary search tree where we have to navigate from one node to another based on some condition, here the difference is that nodes may be of different classes and they inherit a common base.

Comment: Your task specification "use pointers to navigate from one instance of class A to a instance of class B based on some conditions" is too vague to fulfill.

Comment: Its like navigating in a binary search tree where you use left or right pointers to  navigate. But the nodes are of different class. Suppose  a base class Node is there where only key is present. It is inherited by a class RootNode where extra property like *left, *right are present. Another class say InternalNode inherits the Node class whic has properties left, right, parent. Another class Leaf which inherits base has only one property *parent. So differwnt types of nodes are present in the tree. How do I navigate.

Comment: Impossible to say without specifics. Maybe instead show us some code and an error message

Comment: Looks like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Technically, you might be able to use `dynamic_cast<>()`, but highly likely, a better solution of your original problem exists.